# How do I pass void* array to a C function via ctypes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, ctypes

I have a C function in a dll file defined as follows:

```
myFunction(const int a, long b, void * data, unsigned int * c, unsigned int * d, unsigned long * timestamp)
```

Parameters:

```
[in]: a
[in]: b
[out]: data, which is a pointer to a buffer that is maximum of 8 bytes
[out]: c, points to a buffer that receives data message length
[out]: d, pointer to a buffer which receives a message flag
[out]: timestamp, pointer to a buffer which receives message timestamp
```

My python code is as follows:

```
import ctypes

dllhandle = ctypes.WinDLL("dllFile.dll")

a = 1
b = 1738
data = ctypes.c_void_p*8
c = 0
d = 0
timestamp = 0

dllhandle.myFunction(a, b, data, c, d, timestamp)
```

When I run my python code, I get the following error:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 3.
```

I figured this has to do with how I am creating my data buffer pointer array. What is the proper way of creating the data buffer?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array of chars to pass your data. I have written this script that could help you:

```
"""
extern "C" void your_func(void* buffer, int size);
"""
# For Python 2.7
import ctypes

BUFFER_SIZE = 256

# Importing dll
dll = ctypes.CDLL("dllFile.dll")

# Defining C-arguments and output
buffer_c_type = lambda chars: (ctypes.c_char * BUFFER_SIZE)(*map(ctypes.c_char, chars))
size_c_type = ctypes.c_int
restype = None # None is for 'void' as the result of your function in C

# Creating C-arguments having Python variables 'buffer' and 'BUFFER_SIZE'
buffer = "qwdeasdvwergb"
c_buffer = buffer_c_type(buffer)
c_size = size_c_type(BUFFER_SIZE)

# Extracting your_func from dll and setting the type of returning value
your_func = dll["your_func"]
your_func.restype = restype

# Running your_func
your_func(c_buffer, c_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a type, array of void pointers size 8, and is incorrect.

```
data = ctypes.c_void_p*8
```

Instead, you want an instance of some data.  You can use a byte string like `data = 'abcdefg'`.  That would pass an 8-byte value of the ASCII values for the letters plus a null terminator.

If `data` is some kind of structured data, consider [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack):

```
>>> struct.pack('8B',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08'
```

`c`, `d`, `timestamp` need to be a C type to hold an output value:

```
c = ctypes.c_int()
d = ctypes.c_int()
timestamp = ctypes.c_ulong()
```

Use `byref` to pass a reference to these instances to the function, but first it is a good idea to declare the argument types to make sure they are marshaled to the C stack properly.

```
from ctypes import * # for brevity
dllhandle.myFunction.argtypes = c_int,c_long,c_void_p,POINTER(c_int),POINTER(c_int),POINTER(c_ulong)
dllhandle.myFunction.restype = None # for void return

dllhandle.myFunction(a, b, data, byref(c), byref(d), byref(timestamp))
```

View the output values with:

```
print c.value, d.value, timestamp.value
```